# Javascript's split brings to me empty spaces using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, split

My input string is `<img src="hello"/>` and i have to persist only `img` and `hello`.

My regexp is:

```
input = src.split(/<|\s+src="|"\/>/g);
```

... but i get `input=["", "img", "hello", ""]` instead of `input=["img", "hello"]`.

Online regexp javascript split services shows to me correct result, but real javascript don't.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to split by RegExp, when script found that RegExp in the string it will push new element to array. It's the same like if you will try to split by normal string:

```
input = 'xxx';
result = input.split('xxx'); // result = ['', 'xxx', '']
result2 = input.split('x'); // result2 = ['', '', '', '']
```

So let execute Regexp on string:

```
input = '<img src="hello"/>';
reg = /<(.*) src="(.*)"\/>/g;
result = reg.exec(input); // result = ['<img src="hello"/>', 'img', 'hello']
```